# Merge more than 2 SELECT statement in MySQL other than using UNION @ UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Is there any other way to combine more than 2 `SELECT` statements in a MySQL query other than using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`? I already tried using `UNION` and `UNION ALL` but my **query loads too slowly**. This is my query:

```
SELECT 'AVAILABLE' AS STATUS, count(id_status) as BIL
FROM 
book_records AS b, book_class AS c
WHERE p.id_book = k.id_book AND id_status IN ( 1 ) AND class_desc =  'NOVEL'
UNION
SELECT 'WAITING' AS STATUS, count(id_status) as BIL
FROM 
book_records AS b, book_class AS c
WHERE p.id_book = k.id_book AND id_status IN ( 2,3,5 ) AND class_desc =  'NOVEL'
UNION
SELECT 'DAMAGED' AS STATUS, count(id_status) as BIL
FROM 
book_records AS b, book_class AS c
WHERE p.id_book = k.id_book AND id_status NOT IN ( 1,2,3,5 ) AND class_desc =  'NOVEL'
```

Can anyone give me an idea how to solve issue?

Comment: You can use joins instead of union!

Comment: This depends on your query, we might be able to help more if you post your queries. If they are similar in nature (involving the same tables) then you might be able to rewrite your query with some grouped OR conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `p.id_book = k.id_book` actually means `b.id_book = c.id_book`, you could try this alternative:

```
SELECT
  STATUS,
  COUNT(*) AS BIL
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN id_status IN (1)       THEN 'AVAILABLE'
      WHEN id_status IN (2, 3, 5) THEN 'WAITING'
      ELSE                             'DAMAGED'
    END AS STATUS
  FROM
    book_records AS b
  INNER JOIN
    book_class AS c
  ON
    b.id_book = c.id_book
  WHERE
    class_desc =  'NOVEL'
) AS s
GROUP BY
  STATUS
;
```

It may be better because the joined result set will be scanned only once.

By the way, syntactically MySQL allows you to avoid a subselect in this situation and apply `GROUP BY STATUS` directly to the query that defines the `STATUS` computed column. However, that is not standard syntax, and probably very few (if any) other SQL products support it. So, it may be a good idea to refrain from it.

Also, with regard to maintainability and readability, it is better to *always* qualify your columns with the aliases of the tables the columns come from when more than one table is involved in the query, even if the column name is unique.